# How to get nested ValueObject changes?

Tags: javers

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
class Incident {// Id => Entity
  @Id
  String id
  List<Participant> participants
  List<RealEstateProperty> realEstateProperties
}
```

where

```
class Participant {// No id => by javers terms - ValueObject
   EnclosedContact contact
}

class EnclosedContact {// No id => by javers terms - ValueObject
  String name
}

class RealEstateProperty {// No id => by javers terms - ValueObject
   List<CadastralSection> cadastralSections
}

class CadastralSection {// No id => by javers terms - ValueObject
  String sectionId
}
```

I have written the following test (in groovy):

```
def "Querying Javers Repository for participants changes works correctly"() {
    given:
    (1..3).each {
        javers.commit("author", new Incident(
            id: it,
            participants: [
                new Participant(contact: new EnclosedContact(id: 20 + it))
            ]
        ))
    }

    when:
    def snapshots = javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(1, Incident.class, "contact").build())

    then:
    assert snapshots.size() == 1
}
```

The result of this test is:

```
JaversException: PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND property 'contact' not found in class 'Incident'
```

Trying to get the changes this way

```
def snapshots = javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(1, Incident.class, "participants/0/contact").build())
```

returns empty list.

Does Javers support selecting for changes on nested ValueObjects?

Answer (score 2):

in JaVers 1.6.2 there is a basic support for nested ValueObjects queries (undocumented yet). Your query should work for data persisted by this JaVers version. For example:

```
def "should query for changes on nested ValueObjects stored in a list"(){
    given:
    def user = new DummyUserDetails(
        id:1,
        addressList: [new DummyAddress(networkAddress: new DummyNetworkAddress(address: "a"))])

    javers.commit("author", user)
    user.addressList[0].networkAddress.address = "b"
    javers.commit("author", user)

    when:
    def changes = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(1, DummyUserDetails,
            "addressList/0/networkAddress").build())

    then:
    changes.size() == 1
    changes[0].left == "a"
    changes[0].right == "b"
}
```

Comment: is there an easy way to get the path addressList/0/networkAddress programatically?

Comment: is the second level of nesting value objects supported: javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(1, DummyUserDetails,
            "addressList/0/networkAddress/networkCollection/0/networkCollectionValueObject/networkCollectionValueObjectPropertyField").build()) meainig that DumyNetworkAddress having another property addressList1 of type collection

Comment: yes, commit.snapshots[0].globalId.fragment. There is no limits for VO nesting depth

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic nested object comparator, hope it helps.

https://gist.github.com/hank-cp/3db40faed1dd9f02ababd86c2c9eaf8d

Registers it like this way:

```
NestedObjectComparator productRootComparator =
        new NestedObjectComparator<POProductRoot>() {};
sharedJavers = JaversBuilder.javers()
        .registerValue(POProductRoot.class)
        .registerCustomComparator(productRootComparator, POProductRoot.class).build();
productRootComparator.setJsonConverter(sharedJavers.getJsonConverter());
```

Then your will get the changes result in `MapChange` format.

Answer (score 0):

Since JaVers 2.1, there is a new filter for this type of queries - [child-value-objects-filter](http://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#child-value-objects-filter)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I already saw that the version 2.1 supports querying for nested value objects. Currently I have faced a use case where I need to set the versions of snapshots objects that I store in the data store e.g 1.1, 2.2 etc. but it seems that this feature is not supposed to be supported at all in JaVers.